# Is gravity a force? Can there be a new BETTER theory for it?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, spacetime, interactions

what I'm asking is simple in look, but actually, it goes into depth and is complicated. Can there be a new better theory for gravity? and how and why is it not a force? it seems like the theory's the past generations have came up with can be improved and maybe even incorrect in some places. Also can someone explain the concepts and equations that Einstein layed out to prove that gravity is not a force. and is his theory 100% correct? Can there be other possibilities? And also could gravity and weight be the same knowing that your weight changes depending on where you are (moon, earth, mars, etc.)so does your gravity? Could people have misinterpretated this and missed the fact that weight and gravity may be the same and objects generate gravitational fields by bending the geometry of the surrounding space-time?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried reading some of the other relevant questions on this site about gravity, or some introductory articles of websites about gravity and general relativity?

Comment: Newton said “we have explained the phenomena Of the heavens and the sea by the power of gravity but have not yet assigned a cause of that power. I have not been able to discover the cause of those properties of gravity from phenomena and frame no hypothesis”               General relativity does not frame a hypothesis either. For instance how does mass bend space-time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's great that you want to get involved with physics and make your own theory of gravity.

Einstein's General theory of Relativity should certainly be a very close approximation to any future theory that might be produced, but it may not be perfect.

There is still the problem that it hasn't been combined with quantum mechanics and in the places where gravity is really strong, there might be problems - it predicts singularities, places of infinite density.  In the history of physics, when a theory has predicted an infinity it's often been a sign that there is a problem.

Einstein was aware that your weight would change in proportion to your mass if you were to go to the moon for example - perhaps look into the principle of equivalence.

You'll need to be willing to study maths to understand all the details.

Good luck with your studies, hopefully the virus hasn't disrupted the year 9s too much!

Answer (score 2):

From the physicists point of view very probably we once will have a "better" theory of gravity because for now Einstein's theory of gravity and Quantum mechanics are not compatible. There is research in many directions to achieve this, none of the actual proposed theories have convinced the physics community yet. The challenge to achieve this that there are practically no experimental data which could point out the way to go. The research in this field is mainly based on the question to find a consistent theory that makes gravity and quantum mechanics compatible. That said, Einstein's theory for now agrees perfectly the experimental data like perihelion motion of mercury around the sun, the very famous light deviation by gravity, gravitational waves and signal propagation along heavy gravitating bodies for only list up a few of them. And that will not change, even with a new theory there will be this perfect agreement since the new theory has to agree with Einstein's theory on a macroscopical level.

Only on the microscopic level --- i.e. on scales which are much smaller than an atom --- actually on the atomic level due to the weakness of gravitation there is nothing to expect in difference to electromagnetism which is much stronger than gravitation. Actually physicists only expect quantum mechanical effects of gravity (which would indeed require a "better" theory for an appropiate description) on the distances of the size of the Planck length which is $10^{-35}$m that is $10^{-25}$ times smaller than an atom of $10^{-10}$m (also called 1 Angstrom), a scale which very probably can never be reached by experiments. But it could have had an effect extremely shortly after the big-bang on the evolution of the universe which could may be detected even in an universe of macroscopical scale, i.e. our universe of today. May be if we would have this "better" theory we would be able to make consistently quantum mechanics on closed timelike curves or understand better black holes. For instance we might be able to better know what happens inside a black hole, knowing if in the center there is a singularity or not...

As the starting point for the construction of a "better" theory mainly consists of making gravity and quantum mechanics consistent  and due to a lack of experimental data, it requires an extremely good understanding of both. That is the journey to undertake ... I invite you to join.

But all this will have no effect on our daily-life experience of gravity, it will be perfectly the same as ever  and this daily-life experience will perfectly fit with Newton's gravity theory (including that the weight of a body is different on Mars or moon than on Earth -- that can easily be explained by Newton's gravity) For fun you might for instance check the positions of stars during an eclipse close to the shielded sun and compare them later to their position when the sun is not in the way between us and these stars. But still then it is in the realm of Einstein's gravitational theory, it does not need a "better" theory. Nevertheless the latter is already so mind-blowing that it made Einstein world-famous from one day to the other.

In order to wrap up in simple words: A "better" theory of gravity actually hides so well away that it will require the best of the best minds  in the whole history of mankind  to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, gravity is not a force (see for example [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRr1kaXKBsU) video). When you stand on the Earth you only feel the electromagnetic force pushing you up. As long as masses are not accelerated by one of the three basic forces (which **are** forces) they will always move without acceleration. When moving in the gravitational field, no masses experience a force. They are moving in a gravitational field the same way as they are moving in an empty space without gravitation.

Secondly, Einsteinian spacetime gives a good picture of spacetime. When looking at tiny distances, though, this image becomes inadequate (so it is presumed), because of quantum effects which are thought to be applicable to spacetime as well as other features of reality. How to imagine such modifications of spacetime at small distances. A good approach is loop quantum gravity (a nice article about this approach can be found [here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/atoms-of-space-and-time-2006-02/#:%7E:text=A%20theory%20with%20the%20strange,indeed%20made%20of%20discrete%20pieces.&text=Best%20of%20all%2C%20it%20is,if%20they%20are%20really%20there.)). In this approach it is really spacetime that is quantized, in contrast to string theory.